# Sum of two categorical distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have two independent categorical random variables $X_1 \sim Categorical(p_1, \dots, p_n) $ and $X_2 \sim Categorical(q_1, \dots, q_n) $, what is the distribution of $Y = (X_1 + X_2)/2$? Is it right $Y \sim Categorical(\frac{p_1+q_1}{2}, \dots, \frac{p_n+q_n}{2})$?

Comment: No, it's not. It will be a convolution of $Cat_{\frac{X_{1}}{2}} * Cat_{\frac{X_{2}}{2}}$

Comment: @Joitandr can you explain further?